Individual command for section and toc only
I am trying to get the following output as section header/toc:
Text 1    Section Name
1.1    Subsection Name
1.2    Subsection Name
Text 2    Section Name
2.1    Subsection Name
2.1.1    Subsubsection Name
2.1.2    Subsubsection Name
2.2    Subsection Name
Text 3    Section Name
3.1    Subsection Name
3.2    Subsection Name

So basically I want to add a text only to the \section command.
I tried changing the command but it always adds the text also for sub(sub)sections and also the alignment in the toc was off. The code I used was the following:
\documentclass{article}
% Redefine \thesection to display "Phase" before section number
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Text \arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Section}
This is a section.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\section{Section}
This is a section
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
This is a subsubsection.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
This is a subsubsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\section{Section}
This is a section
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}


Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Should the "Text" prefix show up just in the table of contents, or in the actual section-level headers as well? Please advise.

@Mico the prefix should be in both - body and toc

Note: Using overleaf is no reason for tag [tag:overleaf]. Your question is a general LaTeX question not depending on the used editor. So I've removed the tag. Use the tag only for questions depending on usage of overleaf, but also note, that most of those questions are better asked to the overleaf support team and are often closed as off-topic on TeX.SX.

You could additionally redefine \thesubsection:
\documentclass{article}
% Redefine \thesection to display "Phase" before section number
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Text \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\makeatletter\xpatchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{4em}{}{}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Section}\label{sec}
This is a section numbered \ref{sec}.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\section{Section}
This is a section
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
This is a subsubsection.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
This is a subsubsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\section{Section}
This is a section
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}

But note, that the redefinition of \thesection also changes the result of \ref{sec}.
Additionally you should redefine \l@section (commented line in the code above), otherwise the number overlaps in the ToC:

After activation of the commented lines:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter\xpatchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{4em}{}{}\makeatother

you would get:

Things like these are easier using a more configurable class like scrartcl instead of article:
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,10pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{Text~\thesection\enskip}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth,entrynumberformat=\prefixby{Test~}]{section}{section}
\newcommand*{\prefixby}[2]{#1#2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Section}\label{sec}
This is a section numbered \ref{sec}.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\section{Section}
This is a section
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
This is a subsubsection.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
This is a subsubsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\section{Section}
This is a section
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\subsection{Subsection}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}

As you can see, in this example the result of \ref{sec} does not contain the Text used for the heading and the ToC entry:

For more information about \DeclareTOCStyleEntry and its options and also \sectionformat (and maybe also \sectionmarkformat) see the KOMA-Script documentation, which is available in English and German.

This is what I am looking for but the toc is still "messed up"

@Tom As I told, to avoid this, you need to activate the two commented lines.

Sorry -- didn't see it. Thanks for the answer

How would one have to adjust the code so that it's compatible with the needs of a cross-referencing package such as cleveref?

@Mico Your question is unclear, because you do not explain the expected result or which code? But also see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how

@cabohah - Either one. :-)

@Mico Both work with cleveref (with different results). And because it is unclear, which result you expect, I cannot answer your question. If you have a follow-up question please ask a new question and specify the expected result.

I don't know what's supposed to be unclear about my follow-up question. Take, say, your first solution. If I add \usepackage{cleveref} in the preamble, affix the instructions \label{sec:1} and \label{sec:3} to the first and third \section directive, and add the instruction \cref{sec:1,sec:3} somewhere in the body of the document, I get "sections Text 1 and Text 3". I think most people would prefer either "sections 1 and 3" or "texts 1 and 3".

@Mico This is your interpretation, but it highly depends on the prefix text and so others may want another output. And my last example would already have another result, which also could be expected or not. But you are free to ask a question about it. The question here does not include the usage of cleveref (or zref-clever or hyperref or …). I've just answered the shown question. As already told: If you have a follow-up question you should ask a new question. Comments are highly unsuitable for this. See the link I gave you above.

@Mico Sorry for the typo. Please do not read too much into simple typos. I can assure you that I absolutely reject name bashing.

I think you could have answered my follow-up question simply by saying "If being able to use the cleveref machinery is important, I suggest the use of the second solution." No need to demand I post an entirely new question, for sure.

(Edited the answer after receiving additional information from the OP.)
The following solution comes in three parts:

It uses the machinery of the tocloft package to insert the string "Phase " before the numbers of section-level entries in the table of contents.

It modifies the low-level \section@cntformat macro to prefix the string "Phase " to section-level headers, without affecting either the appearance of subsection-level headers or the appearance of cross-references to section-level headers.

Optional: If the cleveref cross-referencing package is used, it issues a \crefname instruction so that \cref and \crefrange continue to work properly, with the only change being that "phase" instead of "section" is used as the word label.



...

\documentclass{article}

%% part 1
\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{Phase }
\addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{\widthof{Phase }}

%% part 2
\makeatletter
% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{Phase \thesection\quad} % section-level entries
\makeatother

%% part 3 (optional)
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{phase}{phases}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Main results} \label{sec:main}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Conclusion} \label{sec:conc}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\bigskip
Cross-references to \cref{sec:intro,sec:conc} of the project.
\end{document}


Hey - your interpretation is indeed incorrect. I want to add a prefix string on the section level only but want to have the prefix in the body of the text as well as in the toc.

@Tom - Thanks for providing this clarification. Please see my updated answer, which also handles the issue of how to create cross-references to section-level entries.
